# How to use two different 404 Error page in laravel

Tags: laravel

How can we show two different error pages to admin? Suppose a user type wrong url from admin panel and it show error belongs to admin and other error page for just website.

Here is my customized code in app/exception/handler:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {

            if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {

                if (request()->is('admin/*')) {
                    if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                        return response()->view('errors.' . '405', [], 404);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                        return response()->view('errors.' . '404', [], 404);
                    }
                }
            }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

// Here is the solution for creating two different error pages one for after beginning the admin prefix and other for simple website

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {

            if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {

                if (request()->is('admin/*')) {
                    if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                        return response()->view('errors.' . '405', [], 404);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                        return response()->view('errors.' . '404', [], 404);
                    }
                }


            }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for making two diffrent 404 pages in laravel 9 i.e for admin **admin_404** and for other users **404**
Go to `app/exception/handler`

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception) {

    if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {

        if (request()->is('admin/*')) {
            if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                return response()->view('errors.' . 'admin_404', [], 404);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                return response()->view('errors.' . '404', [], 404);
            }
        }


    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

This works for me
I'm Using Laravel 9.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Throwable;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return $this->handleNotFoundError($request);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}

private function handleNotFoundError($request)
{
    $route = $request->path();
    if (empty(trim($route, '/'))) {
        return response()->view('candidate.errors.404');
    }

    $segments = explode('/', $route);
    $firstSegment = $segments[0];

    if ($firstSegment === 'admin') {
        return response()->view('admin.errors.404');
    } elseif ($firstSegment === 'recruiter') {
        return response()->view('recruiter.errors.404');
    }

    return response()->view('candidate.errors.404');
}
```